# How to remove a property added to a class instance with Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

It seems I can't just delete it, check it:

```js
class classy {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "I am classy";
  }
}

var o = new classy();
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {"get":()=>"hello"});

console.log("testing o.b = " + o.b);

delete o.b;

console.log("deleted o.b = " + o.b);
```

Comment: A non-configurable property cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of `configurable` is `false` so you should set it to `true` to be able to delete that property..

```js
class classy {
  constructor() {
    this.a = "I am classy";
  }
}

var o = new classy();
Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {
  "get": () => "hello",
  configurable: true
});

delete o.b;
console.log(o.b)
```